# copy in a row manner in Matlab or reshaping dimension

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of 5 x 2611 + 1 dangling and I want to get from the same matrix `96x136` matrix 
what I was thinking is to copy each row until it completes the 136 and so on. However, I don't know where to begin with or which function is the best to do the trick. 
for example:

```
 [2 3 5 6 7;
 8 9.555 10.888 20.888 3.5;
 .........................;
  ......................   5]
```

so the matrix looks like 5*2611 + 1
I know that mat would not accept it in one row and one column because the above dimension is 2611*5
at the end I have one last element

change it in a row manner 
to be 
`2 3 5 6 7 8 9.555 10.888 20.888 3.5 ........ 5`  until the end of 136 column 
and start a new row with the same order.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use transpose and `reshape`:

```
A = [ 2 3 5 6 7 8;...
      9 10 11 12 13];
B = reshape( A.', [3 4] ).';
```

`B` will be of size [4 3] with elements ordered according to **row** stacking of `A`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a matrix of `5*2611` elements you can:

1. reshape it into a vector with one row, eg `vec1 = reshape(mat1',1,5*2611)`
2. tack on the extra value, eg `vec1 = [vec1 dangler]`
3. reshape into a matrix again `mat2 = reshape(vec1,96,136)`

and, if I got the transpose right, you have the matrix you're looking for.  If I didn't get the transpose right @Shai will come along and correct me.